# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Can anyone help me out?

I don't know why the following SQL gives a syntax error:

```
if not exists (select 1 from sysobjects where type='U' and name='pg_result')
    create table pg_result (parent char(10), child char(10)) 
else
    delete from pg_result
end if
```

I'm getting the following error:

> [Error] Script lines: 141-146
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.
>
> Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 2
>
> Server: SYBDEV, Line: 5

I'm running:

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.4/EBF 16785 ESD#10/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.8/ase1254/2159/64-bit/FBO/Mon Nov  2 13:08:08 2009

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if not exists (select 1 from sysobjects where type='U' and name='pg_result')
    create table pg_result (parent char(10), child char(10)) 
else
    delete from pg_result
```

or

```
if not exists (select 1 from sysobjects where type='U' and name='pg_result')
begin
    create table pg_result (parent char(10), child char(10)) 
end
else
begin
    delete from pg_result
end
```

see 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands61.htm

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `end` if you don't use a `begin`